# PHP sending message via TCP/IP

Tags: php, arduino, tcp

Im try to send a Message from PHP Website via TCP/IP to an Arduino.

With following code i'm able to send a message from php website

```
<?php 
$errno = NULL;
$error = NULL;

if (!$handle = @fsockopen("192.168.188.24", "49419", $errno, $error, 10))
{
   die("Fehler (".$errno."): ".$error);
}

fwrite($handle, "ON\r\n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The problem is, when calling the website for the first time, the message doesnt get delivered immediatly. Just after some refreshes of the website, the message arrives, but logical so many times like amount of website refreshes.

Already tried to limit the messagelength to 2bytes, but without any success.

Comment: Is the Arduino setup to listen for TCP messages properly? https://evothings.com/doc/examples/arduino-led-onoff-tcp.html

Comment: yes, it is. like already said, it's able to receive messages. Got displayed the the content on console. There isnt a certain number of refreshes, until the message/s arrive/s. When calling the website for first time, it just should send the message immediatly, and it does not.

Comment: Well, i tried the same with addison controller. seems like arduino has to be setup again, because addison received messages immediatly!

Conclusion: PHP is fine and works like this! Thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  inside a `try - catch` block.

```
    try {

    } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

To see what exception you may get.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)