# How can we run a C code using php code written and uploaded on a website?

Tags: php, c

I am working on a task that requires running a C code on my PC using a PHP code on a website created by me so how can that be possible using the IP and Port Number of my PC ?

I've searched for some codes to do that task but haven't find enough what i demand , it's quite similar to this in that question : [PHP sending message via TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178912/php-sending-message-via-tcp-ip?fbclid=IwAR37XCjm4xkMjpeuhipEtKS1a3CIbltvZ5auyyrHbxrkI55OgnA3ilU4bbc)
but not exactly and the code inlink is :

```
<?php 
$errno = NULL;
$error = NULL;

if (!$handle = @fsockopen("192.168.188.24", "49419", $errno, $error, 10))
{
   die("Fehler (".$errno."): ".$error);
}

fwrite($handle, "ON\r\n");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Well, since not working with Arduino , i hope it's possible to compile and run code remotely from the website

Answer (score 0):

You either need a `static IP address` and to open up the ports you need on your PC both incoming and out going...

... or you need a dynamic IP service that will pretty much give your PC a domain name you can access, and will update your IP everytime it changes (usually when restarting router). 
 You will still need to open the ports you require.

Many ISP will give you a static IP though, so if you have a static IP, you can just use that.

DynIP is a good example of a dynamicIP address: https://www.dynip.com/

Simple install, but it's paid for. There's probably free alternatives out there.

Or... get a server on AWS or similar, and host the C script on there, and call that server, rather than your home PC.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you've got a `C` program on your local computer, that you want to run from a remote website. Your local PC is simply a client and not offering any services. That's not possible for security reasons. Imagine what the internet would be like if servers could start running programs on random PC's.

You need to set up your local PC as a server, and offer the C program through it; possibly a web service running CGI.

On another note, `192.168.188.24` is a local IP address, behind a router; I don't think your website can talk to it unless it's also behind the same router.

Comment: Or you could make a client on the local machine which is then the interface between the server and the computer as most of those interactions is done.